# Eclipse Android error No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, eclipse

What should I do with this problem in the eclipse consol?(sorry Iam not very god at write english)

```
[2015-11-26 21:35:07 - First] D:\AndroidWorks\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:106: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2015-11-26 21:35:07 - First] 
[2015-11-26 21:35:07 - First] D:\AndroidWorks\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2015-11-26 21:35:07 - First] 
[2015-11-26 21:35:07 - First] D:\AndroidWorks\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2015-11-26 21:35:07 - First] 
[2015-11-26 21:35:07 - First] D:\AndroidWorks\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:50: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2015-11-26 21:35:07 - First] 
[2015-11-26 21:35:07 - First] D:\AndroidWorks\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:55: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2015-11-26 21:35:07 - First] 
[2015-11-26 21:35:07 - First] D:\AndroidWorks\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
```

And statements example this.
(My project name is "first")

thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you were trying to do,for the error to occur and the final result you  want?

Comment: I think you missed the reference library in your project. If you work with material library add that as a library project .

Comment: @ColnsAbt after create android application project errors show to eclipse console

Comment: [can this be it](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72991)

Answer (score 0):

Set your api-level 21 like below in your project property.

[image]

for Android studio set it like below in build.gradle

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  // ...

  defaultConfig {
    // ...
    targetSdkVersion 21
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse open your project.properties file(appcompat lib) and edit the target to android-21 or above **warning** you should not do this manually change it using properties.

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-23
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
```